# How can I successfully save JPGs that are embedded in Excel rows and subsequently transfer that file to another location?

Tags: microsoft-excel, export

Title is a bit confusing, I'll admit, but it's because I've never encountered this problem before and it's further complicated by the fact that I'm dealing with this person remotely and their computer skills are limited.

They have a spreadsheet / inventory of artworks which is represented individually by a number of rows (sometimes 2, sometimes 3), the first column containing the images that are embedded (low-res JPGs), with subsequent columns containing information. Each record is a number of rows due to the embedded image.

My question is: How does one successfully save an Excel file that captures the embedded images? The problem area for us has been the unsuccessful transfer of this file to us via email or file transferring services.

My guess is that the spreadsheet is saved one place and the images she is referencing from is saved in another, and so, when they go to save, they're only saving the data and not the images.

Some info: This excel spreadsheet is exported from an ArtSystems database which may or may not be the root of our problems.

EDIT: The error message that shows up after they attempt to save and send me the file reads -- "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted, Verify that the link points to the correct file and..." before it cuts out.

I guess it is a matter of saving BOTH the data and the images, but I'm unsure how that differs from a normal Save As...

Answer (score 0):

XLSX file type is a container for a bunch of media. To access all embedded images as their original filetypes (gif/jpg/etc), Right click on the .xlsx file and unzip it (7-zip works well for this). Then, you can go in that folder and navigate to `xl\media` and see all the embedded images.

Comment: Strangely you do not need to manipulate it with a zip program, you can just change the extension to .zip and navigate the folder in windows explorer.

Comment: I can access the images outside of the XLSX document just fine. But, since I'm trying to make life for researchers easier, I'd like for the images to remain embedded in their corresponding Excel rows/records. They seem to become unlinked as they travel the virtual ether. The images themselves are in a separate folder that also got delivered to me via Dropbox. My guess is that once the export from the database took place, the database created the XLSX spreadsheet (w/ the embedded images) as well as the folder of images. I'm starting to feel like there isn't a solution short of manually doing it